# creating nx project for angular, using module federation and ssr

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, nomachine-nx, angular-module-federation

I have tried to build `nx` project using module federation, and server-side rendering, I have followed the instructions written in the following official guide https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/module-federation-with-ssr, but I when I ran the `npx nx` `serve-ssr` store, I got the error -

```
 Shared module is not available for eager consumption: 4124
    at Object.__webpack_require__.m.<computed> (./webpack/runtime/consumes:165:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (./webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at 5297 (C:\Users\itama\work\dist\store\server\main.js:18:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (./webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at <anonymous> (./webpack/bootstrap:37:81)
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (./webpack/runtime/chunk%20loaded:25:1)
    at __webpack_require__.x (./webpack/bootstrap:38:1)
```

I tried to add configuration to the addtional-shared and even the shared itself in the
`module-federation.config.ts` but it didn't fix the problem no matter what I tried.

all i tried to do was running the project, and it failed it the :server part of the remote apps.
also i'm running on windows enviroment.